# trying to use CMake on macOS and this happens: CMake Error at ipsw-patch/CMakeLists.txt:19 (message): libcrypto is required for ipsw

Tags: ios, macos, cmake, openssl, libcrypto

this is my first time posting here, so sorry for my post formatting and terminology maybe not being correct.
I am trying to use CMake to make a program called "xpwn" on macOS. the CMakeLists.txt file contains this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project (XPwn)

# We want win32 executables to build staticly by default, since it's more difficult to keep the shared libraries straight on Windows
IF(WIN32)
    SET(BUILD_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "Force compilation with static libraries")
ELSE(WIN32)
    SET(BUILD_STATIC OFF CACHE BOOL "Force compilation with static libraries")
ENDIF(WIN32)

IF(BUILD_STATIC)
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
ENDIF(BUILD_STATIC)

include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes)

add_subdirectory (common)
add_subdirectory (minizip)
add_subdirectory (dmg)
add_subdirectory (hdutil)
add_subdirectory (hfs)
add_subdirectory (ipsw-patch)
add_subdirectory (dfu-util)
add_subdirectory (xpwn)
add_subdirectory (idevice)
add_subdirectory (pwnmetheus2)
add_subdirectory (dripwn)

install(FILES README.markdown DESTINATION . RENAME README.txt)
install(FILES LICENSE DESTINATION . RENAME LICENSE.txt)

IF(WIN32 OR APPLE)
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
ELSE(WIN32 OR APPLE)
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "TBZ2")
ENDIF(WIN32 OR APPLE)

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "XPwn")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "iPhone Dev Team")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.markdown")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.markdown")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "5")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "8")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "xpwn" "XPwn Pwner")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "ipsw" "IPSW Tool")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "hdutil" "Apple disk image utility")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "dmg" "Apple DMG utility")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "hfsplus" "Apple HFS+ utility")
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

and the terminal spits out

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error at ipsw-patch/CMakeLists.txt:19 (message):
  libcrypto is required for ipsw!


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

any ideas on how I might solve this? if there's any other documentation that I'd need, please let me know

update: its even more confusing now...

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/lib/libcrypto.dylib (found version "1.1.1k")  
CMake Error at ipsw-patch/CMakeLists.txt:19 (message):
  libcrypto is required for ipsw!


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

it seems like it found it? but it didn't?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but it happened with `openssl@3`. To fix it, I just changed the files:

1. `/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib`
2. `/usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib`
3. `/usr/local/include/openssl`

to link to `openssl@1.1` and am able to compile now.

For me, brew automatically installed `openssl@3` so I had to install `openssl` again to get the lower version.

Comment: Thank for you guy who edit my answer so grandma is correct now , thank